# Sentence correction confusion

Tags: sentence-choice

Kuntal **managed**(a) to **jump out**(b) of the window before the police **could trace**(c) where he **was**(d) hiding. No error(e)

The given answer is (a) while I thought (e) is correct one. I'm thinking the correct structure should be "Had managed". Is my assumption correct or should it be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The past tense is quite reasonable here.  There is no need for the past perfect just because the word "before" has been used.

You could also use the past perfect.  The choice would depend on how this sentence fits into the larger narrative. It is nearly impossible to write sentences that require the past perfect to be grammatically correct.

However clearly the educational point here is that when one event occurs "before" the time that the narrative is describing, then the past perfect may be used.

Comment: So (e) isn't necessarily incorrect? As there are no added sentences or paragraphs.

Comment: Yes.  there is not necessarily an error here.

Comment: @eefar I don't know where you got it. But this type of questions are asked in exams in India. Even for writing a correct answer you will be marked in red. Just like this one. Here only one answer is not possible.

Comment: Yes this is from a test in India. could you kindly elaborate how one answer is not possible?

Comment: @eefar James in his answer clearly states that either (a) or (e) is correct.

Comment: What matters more? Learning English, or getting marks in the test?  For getting marks in the test the clear answer is (a) because that is what your teacher wants you to answer. But actually there is no error in this sentence.

Comment: James it is unfortunate that the teacher only wants (a) as an answer. It is baseless. Yes he might say Past Participle should be used, there is no denying. But at the same time, there is no denying that you are good to go even without Past Participle. The sentence as it is is correct. You write one way or the other, both are correct and mean the same thing.